# How to free up space in this panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Wanting to make space for a hot tub circuit (50a - 2 pole). NEC 2023 in Colorado USA.

Thinking use 2 slim double poles to replace the AC disconnect 2 and the cook top and move the furnace circuit to the bottom and shif the AC and Cook top up one so they are 1/2 space off beat to be on separate buses?

[image: main panel]

Also, on this sub, just curious. Is the only thing that can be done is to combine the House GFI and Garage to a slim tandem since they don't make AFCI's in a slim version (that I can find anyway)?

[image: sub panel]

Comment: Garage is now required to have it's own circuit, so combining it is out of the question. https://up.codes/viewer/washington/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.11_(C)_(4)

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I didn't mean combine the garage and house GFI circuits, just putting them in a slim tandem breaker with garage on one breaker and house GFI on the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get an Eaton BQD 250220. Just like this picture but with 50 on inner set.[image: Eaton quad breaker]

Then remove the 2 pole 20Amp for AC2 and use new breaker for ac and spa. That is assuming you are using a spa disconnect with GFCI protection built in. If need GFCI breaker in this panel for spa, then get same breaker in 20 / 30 Amp and combine AC and Water heater.

Answer (score 3):

Have you done a [NEC 220.82 Load Calculation](https://www.cityofsacramento.org/-/media/Corporate/Files/CDD/Building/Forms/CDD-0213_Electrical-Load-Calculation-Worksheet.pdf?la=en) on this panel? It looks kinda maxed out, and I'm not sure there's room for 50A more load.

I agree with Keith that you can tandem up some of the 240V loads smaller than 60A.  But this is getting pretty sketch with all the load.

Not sure why that subpanel is so small, 100A can power a lot more than 12 spaces of stuff especially when A/GFCIs are involved.  I think your best bet is replace with a 24-30 space.  Note that the breaker bus rating is like car tire speed rating, it absolutely can and should exceed the feed breaker. But yes, you can install a BRD2xx2115 quadplex, with the 15A singles on the outside.   xx being your 240V amps.

Note that under NEC 2023, virtually all 240V circuits now need GFCI, but feeders don't if you are feeding a subpanel.